# Remove First and Last Characters in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have trouble in creating this formula.

I want to remove the first and last character of the value in column F
ex. the output is **12345_GEE45678_OF_ABCDEFGHIJK**

from that I want it be like this **GEE45678**
I tried to combine the Right And Left formula in excel but it didn't work.

thank you so much!!

Comment: VBA: `Split("12345_GEE45678_OF_ABCDEFGHIJK", "_")(1)`

Comment: Formula: `=MID(A1,1+FIND("_",A1),FIND("_",A1,1+FIND("_",A1))-FIND("_",A1)-1)`

Comment: @Akina, can you post as an answer so others can find this question and solution?

Comment: @jrichall Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA:

```
Split("12345_GEE45678_OF_ABCDEFGHIJK", "_")(1)
```

Formula:

```
=MID(A1,1+FIND("_",A1),FIND("_",A1,1+FIND("_",A1))-FIND("_",A1)-1)
```